# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in D:\Bureau\Codage\Wamp\www\index.php on line 5

Tags: php

When I execute this code it says to me the error in the title.
The code:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name=$_POST['name']

        echo 'test';
}
```

I know it's a little code but I don't find the error.
Can you help me pls?

Comment: PHP is not JS, place `;` in the end of your second line

Comment: Semi colon (;) is missing after second line $_POST[‘name’] it should be like $name =$_POST[‘name’];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing semmicolon at end of the  line.
$name=$_POST['name'];

Comment: oh yeah thank you a very stupid error